# What is the meaning of "Marine Fares" regarding airline baggage?

Tags: air-travel, luggage, terminology, fares

The [terms of an airline company](http://www.airserbia.com/en/checked-or-registered-baggage) regarding their checked baggage rules refers to two concepts: Piece and weight. A section of the "weight" concept mentions "Marine Fares of Economy Class". What does this "marine" mean for me as a passenger?

Comment: [greyshade's answer](http://travel.stackexchange.com/a/35607/11491) seems like a reasonable interpertation. Given the... idiosyncratic nature of the English on the page you link, I suspect that, if there is a standard term for this, it's not "Marine Fares". (Generally, "marine" refers to the sea; "maritime" refers to ships, sailors and so on.)

Comment: A lot of airlines seem to have special conditions for seamen having to travel from one port to another via plane.

Comment: @DavidRicherby Another guess might be that their use of the term 'marine' is and accidental 'generalisation' of the term 'marine' as in 'navy soldier' to seamen in general - though all of these speculations might be more a topic for [english.SX](http://english.stackexchange.com/)..

Comment: @greyshade In one of those moments of clarity that comes when you see something again after not thinking about it for a few hours, the word they actually want is almost certainly "mariner", i.e., sailor.

Comment: @DavidRicherby well, there you go - you're most probably right there.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

On the page for [excess baggage charges](http://www.airserbia.com/en-gr/excess-baggage-charges) there's a separate section

> For seamen traveling within Europe

which strongly suggests that's what your "Marine" refers to - a seaman.